# selectonemenu options far from the menu box itself

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 3.2 and running app on Tomcat 7.0. I have pretty big form and a couple of `<p:selectOneMenu>` boxes at the bottom of the form. When I click on that box, then the options appear at the top of the form, so I have to scroll back to the top to select option. Is there a way to keep options close to the menu box?

Comment: Do you mean to say that the list is detached from the select box and floating at the top of the form? This is not normal and would be a CSS bug. Does this occur in all browsers? Does this also still occur when you upgrade to PrimeFaces 3.3?